# Rails app generating wrong :id in parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, nested-resources

I am creating a very basic rails app for the first time with 2 resources, Departments(depts) and Members. I believe I have used nested resources correctly, but for some reason after running rails server, the :id for the parent resource is not being generated/passed correctly. Root is the depts#index and from here I can do new and edit using _form.haml rendered in the new and edit views. However, when I do /depts/3 I get error with "can't find dept with id=3". Clicking through to edit from index gives me /depts/63/edit in the URL - I'm not sure where this id=63 has come from. Trying to get to 'show' action by typing /dept/63 in the URL does not work. I created Depts on it's own at first, got it working with all actions and views, something has gone wrong since I added Members resource.

routes.rb

```
        resources :depts do
  resources :members
end
```

depts_controller.rb

```
    def index
        @depts = Dept.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render :json => @depts }
        end
      end

      def show
        @dept = Dept.find(params[:dept_id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render :json => @dept }
        end
      end

      def new
        @dept = Dept.new(params[:dept])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render :json => @dept }
        end
      end

      def create
        @dept = Dept.new(params[:dept])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @dept.save
             format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
             format.json { render :json => @dept }
          else
             format.html { render :action => 'new' }
             format.json { render :json => @dept }
          end
        end
      end

      def edit
        @dept = Dept.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @dept = Dept.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @dept.update_attributes(params[:dept])
             format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index'}#, :id => @dept }
             format.json { render :json => @dept }

          else
             format.html { redirect_to :action => 'edit' }
             format.json { render :json => @dept }
          end
        end
      end

    def destroy
        @dept = Dept.find(params[:id])
        @dept.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
          format.json { render :json => @dept }
        end
      end
    end
```

show.haml

```
    %p= @dept.name

    %p= link_to "back", {:action => 'index'}
```

index.haml

```
    %h1 DEPARTMENTS

    %ol
      - @depts.each do |d|
        %li= link_to d.name
        %p= link_to 'edit department', edit_dept_path(d)
        %p= link_to 'get rid of department!', d, :method => :delete, :id => d.id

      %br
    %p= link_to "ADD A NEW DEPARTMENT", new_dept_path
```

Answer (score 0):

in show method change:

```
@dept = Dept.find(params[:dept_id])
```

to:

```
@dept = Dept.find(params[:id])
```

and in new method change:

```
@dept = Dept.new(params[:dept])
```

to just:

```
@dept = Dept.new
```